# Execute function on height change using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I wan to run a function on div height change, I want to add a class to body if div height increased and remove the class if height decrease to `0`.

Something like:

```
$('.mydiv').change(function(){
    // add class to boy if height increase
})
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726406/how-to-detect-and-change-div-height-in-jquery?rq=1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting when a div's height changes using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/172821/detecting-when-a-divs-height-changes-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.mydiv').resize(function() {
  if($(this).height() > 400){
    $('body').removeClass('normal height bigheight').addClass('bigheight');
  } else if ($(this).height() > 200){
    $('body').removeClass('normal height bigheight').addClass('height');
  } else if ($(this).height() > 0){
    $('body').removeClass('normal height bigheight').addClass('normal');
  } else {
    $('body').removeClass('normal height bigheight');
  }
});
```