# how can i build a numeric counter that scretchs to unlimited number

Tags: php, javascript, html

well the title matches what im in search for but to narrow it down ;),

im look for a numeric counter to add to my webpage, i wish the numbers to stretch to a unlimited value, adding numeric data from a table add to the counter without reset the counter by too 0.

would be entirely grateful for anyone that can help :)

```
<script>
('.myClassAbleToAddOnCounter').bind('click', function(){

var currentCount = parseInt($('#myCounterTotal').html());

var countToAdd = parseInt($(this).html());


('#myCounterTotal').html( currentCount + countToAdd );

});</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you go on that question on your first post at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017229/execute-function-on-height-change-using-jquery/18017352

Comment: my counter has gone completely madness :(

Answer (score 0):

Example of how you might make a counter in *JavaScript*..

```
function Counter(start) {
    this.value = this._initial = start || 0;
}
Counter.prototype.now = function () { return this.value; };
Counter.prototype.inc = function () { return ++this.value; };
Counter.prototype.add = function (x) { return this.value += x; };
Counter.prototype.reset = function () { return this.value = this.initial; };
```

Then

```
var c = new Counter();
c.inc();  // 1
c.inc();  // 2
c.add(5); // 7
```

Comment: Great thanks, i think thats the functioning done right?,
now i just need to build up a counter template any ideas how this can be achieved?